# extjs shadow bug when dragging panels

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel, draggable, extjs6

I have **three panels** in my [Ext JS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/) project; That is **one panel** as a **parent panel** and two others are **child** panels. I've set the child panels to be draggable.
As you can see in the code below:

```
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.data.TreeStore'],
collapsible: true,
border: false,
draggable: true,
resizable: true,
floating: true,
constrain: true,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
store: new Ext.data.TreeStore({
//data.jason
}),
listeners: {
    move: 'onDrag'
}
```

//onDrag function is:

```
onDrag: function(stick)
{
   stick.dd = new Ext.dd.DDProxy(stick.el.dom.id,'group');
   drag = stick;
   drag.anchorTo(Ext.getBody(),"tl-bl?");
   drag.setHeight(490);
   drag.setMinHeight(200);
}
```

My problem is that when I drag the child panels they leave some shadow on the former place:

[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: could you provide a working fiddle ?

Answer (score 2):

Extjs has a habit of not updating its shadows.

Try `drag.syncShadow();`